# Erro Laravel ao criar o serve

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

Olá, estou tendo problemas ao criar o serve no laravel com o comando (php artisan serve) ele apresenta esse erro. O projeto está criado dentro da pasta php do Xampp, pois não consegui criar um projeto em outra pasta aleatória, o apache está ative, mas continua com o erro.[image: Segue erro na imagem]

Comment: Qual versão do laravel está instalada?

Comment: Nesse projeto é o 5.3

Comment: Verifica se teu server atende todos requisitos de uma instalação laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note que seu servidor está criado e funcional, o erro já faz parte do seu projeto. Note que segundo a documentação Laravel, são necessários pré requisitos no servidor para que tudo funcione corretamente. Parece que seu servidor não tem o OpenSSl Ativo ou instalado. Exemplo de requisitos do Laravel 5.3:

- PHP between 5.6.4 & 7.1.*
- OpenSSL PHP Extension
- PDO PHP Extension
- Mbstring PHP Extension
- Tokenizer PHP Extension
- XML PHP Extension

Referência: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3

Nota, ativando a extensão no php.ini:

1. Vá para o seu php.ini (que é usado pelo xampp)
2. Remova o ponto e vírgula antes extension=php_openssl.dll
3. Reinicie seu Apache

Comment: Estou com o OpenSSl no computador e setado como variável de ambiente, mesmo assim, continua com esse problema

Comment: seu php.ini está com o trecho: extension = php_openssl.dll   descomentado??